# linux & identify the interface name on remote machine

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, ethernet, ping

lets say I want to ping to some machine as from my machine - moon

```
ping -c 1 master01
```

now I want to understand what is the interface name in master01 machine that get the packet from ping

so how we can identify what is the interface name on master01 that packet from moon machine was sent?

Comment: Do you have access to `master01` machine ?

Comment: yes I have , also ssh

Comment: Several options, e.g.: Find the IP address (`host master01`), ssh into master01, find interface with this IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to find out which interface was used on remote machine using ping. You have to login to remote machine and check which interface has assigned IP address you are pinging. You can do it using `ifconfig` or `ip address` commands on Linux, and `ipconfig` command in Windows.

Comment: "_check which interface has [the] assigned IP address_" is not a trivial operation when there is more than one interface.